# If statement to execute different queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query that will run query A if the current date is for example = '2016-12-18' and if not, run query B.

Query A example:

```
SELECT 
    issueDate  Date_Time,
    firstName, player_id Player_ID

FROM
 PlayerNote pn join Brand b 

WHERE
    pn.issueDate >= date_format(date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 month),
   '%Y-%m-01') and pn.issueDate < date_format(curdate() ,'%Y-%m-01')
```

Query B example:

```
SELECT 
        issueDate  Date_Time,
        firstName, player_id Player_ID

    FROM
     PlayerNote pn join Brand b 

    WHERE
        pn.issueDate >= date_format(curdate() ,'%Y-%m-01')
        and pn.issueDate <curdate()
```

I tried to write those two queries in a case statement like :
select case when (curdate()='2016-12-18') then (Query A) ELSE (Query B) end

but received
Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you aware of the Cartesian product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Boolean algebra.

```
SELECT 
    issueDate  Date_Time,
    firstName, player_id Player_ID

FROM
 PlayerNote pn join Brand b 

WHERE
    (curdate()='2016-12-18'
    and pn.issueDate >= date_format(date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 month), '%Y-%m-01') 
    and pn.issueDate < date_format(curdate() ,'%Y-%m-01'))
   or 
   (curdate()<>'2016-12-18'
    and pn.issueDate >= date_format(curdate() ,'%Y-%m-01')
    and pn.issueDate <curdate());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't think about this option

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use "select case when" like that in MySQL. It may work in Oracle (if I remember correctly. Not sure). As I understand, it accept only single value (one row and one column)

For example, you can do this

```
SELECT CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN 'one'
WHEN 2 THEN 'two' ELSE 'more' END;
```

or this

```
SELECT CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN (select 1)
WHEN 2 THEN (select 1) ELSE (select 1) END;
```

but not this (return multiple rows)

```
SELECT CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN (select 1 from anytable)
WHEN 2 THEN (select 1 from anytable) ELSE (select 1 from anytable) END;
```

nor this (return multiple columns)

```
SELECT CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN (select 1,2)
WHEN 2 THEN  (select 1,2) ELSE  (select 1,2) END;
```

I would suggest you do use union and put data condition in each sub queries.
For example

```
SELECT 
    issueDate  Date_Time,
    firstName, player_id Player_ID

FROM
 PlayerNote pn join Brand b 

WHERE
    pn.issueDate >= date_format(date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 month),  '%Y-%m-01') 
     and pn.issueDate < date_format(curdate() ,'%Y-%m-01')
     and curdate()='2016-12-18'

UNION

SELECT 
        issueDate  Date_Time,
        firstName, player_id Player_ID

    FROM
     PlayerNote pn join Brand b 

    WHERE
        pn.issueDate >= date_format(curdate() ,'%Y-%m-01')
        and pn.issueDate <curdate() 
        and curdate()<>'2016-12-18'
```

I did not test it but it should work.